# Set the Image On Button of DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How Do I set the Normal and *Pressed* image to My Button of `DataGridViewButtonColumn` 
Now i'm using image button so i'm able to set the image button how do i set the pressed image.

Actually I want the button clickable which should have image and after click image should be change. Please look at the image below.

Before [image]

After [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try in `CellContentClick event` and this is just an example, I hope you can some idea.

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) //Where your DataGridViewButtonColumn index
        {
            if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "Start")
                {
                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Stop";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Start";
                }
            }
            else
                dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Start";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi spajce. I edited my question, Please look at the images in that last column there are buttons so how do i achive this. Sorry for late replay. Thanks

Comment: I see, you have a third party `dataGridView` right? i apologize i have no idea on that `dataGridView` you're using. by the way, where did you get that `dataGridView`? :)

Comment: Hi,no it's not third party datagridview i have build like this i did't have 3 buttons now. I've Only 1 button column now and want to change the image of it when pressed and normal state.(the image is just made in Photoshop).

Comment: mhmm tricky ha. I can't answer to your problem but you need to create a customize `DataGridViewButtonColumn` in order to achieve that. this is not a `buttonColum` but a `RatingColumn` hopefully you can get some idea from this link. Good luck :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/18/media-player-like-rating-datagridview-column.aspx